# Envelope Tabs removed when using CreateEnvelopeFromTemplates()

Tags: docusignapi

Im using the DocuSign API and im having some issues with the recipient not getting the tabs I save on the website ui. I create a template using DocuSign.com and set the recipient to Role=[testRole] Email=[] Name=[] Type=[Sign] under Recipients and routing. Because I have no recipients yet. Then using the api before i send it out i set the recipient to :

```
        //Recipient Info
        Recipient recipient = new Recipient();
        recipient.Email = recipientEmail;
        recipient.UserName = recipientName;
        recipient.SignerName = recipientName;
        recipient.Type = RecipientTypeCode.Signer;
        recipient.RoleName = recipientRoleName;
        recipient.ID = "1";
        recipient.SignInEachLocationSpecified = true;
        recipient.RoutingOrder = 1;
        Recipient[] recipients = new Recipient[] { recipient };

        //Template reference from server ID
        TemplateReference templateReference = new TemplateReference();
        templateReference.Template = templateID;
        templateReference.TemplateLocation = TemplateLocationCode.Server;

        //Envelope Info
        EnvelopeInformation envelopeInfo = new EnvelopeInformation();
        envelopeInfo.AccountId = AccountID;
        envelopeInfo.Subject = subject;
        envelopeInfo.EmailBlurb = message;
```

I set recipient.RoleName to the same thing as i set on the website UI and still the recipient doesn't get the signature tabs. am i missing something here? Or how do i relate the empty recipient i created using the DocuSign UI to the recipient im sending it to so that it has the tabs present?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out after shooting in the dark for a while. I was so sure the issue was in Recipient but when I took a look at TemplateReference I found RoleAssignments which apparently setting up in Recipient.Role does nothing. You have to set it up in TemplateReference using something like:

```
        //Recipient Role
        var recipientRole = new TemplateReferenceRoleAssignment();
        recipientRole.RecipientID = "101";
        recipientRole.RoleName = recipientRoleName;

        //Template reference from server ID
        TemplateReference templateReference = new TemplateReference();
        templateReference.Template = templateID;
        templateReference.TemplateLocation = TemplateLocationCode.Server;
        templateReference.RoleAssignments = new TemplateReferenceRoleAssignment[] { recipientRole };
```